# Steps in the general computation of the DTFT of a complex signal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform, discrete-time

Given the complex signal

$s[n]=A\cdot e^{j(2\pi f_0 nT_s+\theta)}$

Which is zero-padded to length $M$, I'm trying to compute the steps to obtain its discrete time fourier transform (DTFT).

I'm considering the $k$-th element as:

$S[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}s[n]e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$

Additionally, I'm basing my considerations on the results shown in [1], where it is defined that the following is valid:

$S[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}s[n]e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$=$\frac {A\cdot sin(\pi (f_0 T_s-k/N)M} {sin(\pi(f_0T_s-k/N))} e^{j\pi(f_0T_s-k/N)(M-1)+\theta}$

What I want to do, is understand the mathematical steps between the summation and the explicit form.

References:

[1] XIANG, J., Wei, C. U. I., & Qing, S. H. E. N. (2018). Flexible and accurate frequency estimation for complex sinusoid signal by interpolation using dft samples. Chinese Journal of Electronics, 27(1), 109-114.